# unable to fill a data frame using column names and row names

Tags: r

I have data frame "x" like this :

```
        meme   webId  timeStamp
        2501   68814  281322.1 
        2501    2679  305813.0
        2501     948  306025.6
```

I want to use "meme" and "webId" as row and column names and timeStamp as element in "mat" data frame. I wrote this:

```
cols<-unique(x[,"webId"])

rows<-unique(x[,"meme"])

mat<-data.frame(matrix(data=9999999,nrow=length(rows),ncol=length(cols)))

colnames(mat)<-c(cols)

rownames(mat)<-c(rows)

for(i in 1:length(x))
        mat[rownames(mat)==x[i,"meme"],colnames(mat)==x[i,"webId"]]<-x[i,"timeStamp"]
```

but nothing changed. what is the problem?
please help me!!!

Comment: You don't need a loop. Try `mat[match(rownames(mat), x$meme), match(colnames(mat), x$webId)] <- x$timeStamp`

Comment: @akrun  the error is something like this:  Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, match(rownames(mat), x$meme), match(colnames(mat),  : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Comment: Is it based on the same example you posted?  It is not giving me any errors

Comment: It gives me `mat#
        68814   2679      948
2501 281322.1 305813 306025.6`

Comment: @ZahraAminolroaya Using your code, the output of "mat" looks correct. Do you want x to change?

Comment: memes are 2501 and 52      and     webIds are [1]   68814    2679     948    6382    4155     602    1538   12987
   [9]   16083    4797   15894    3530    2902   20806   11791     830
  [17]    6704    6391   13235    1656    9106    4170     318     144
  [25]   72666    1499    1286   20822   80709      50    6121    1691
  [33]    3468    3696   18926     996   37227   10957    5931    7597
  .........   What would be my mistake? what does  this error mean?

Comment: @highonprogramming . no I want to change mat. when I use my code only the first row changes. <br/>   68814    2679       948    6382    4155     602    1538<br/>2501  281322.1  305813  306025.6 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999<br/>52   9999999.0 9999999 9999999.0 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999<br/> 12987   16083    4797   15894    3530    2902   20806   11791<br/>
2501 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999<br/>
52   9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999

Comment: @ZahraAminolroaya  Please update the new data in your post.  It is not easy to understand the data from the comments due to the formatting.  Also, if you can use `dput` to show the data, it would  be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop, it seems that you mean to iterate over all the rows in x, and fill all the values into mat one by one. Instead you only iterate over 3 rows. `length(x)` gives the number of columns not the number of rows. This is the correct code for iterating over all rows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(x))
        mat[rownames(mat)==x[i,"meme"],colnames(mat)==x[i,"webId"]]<-x[i,"timeStamp"]
```

I suspect that the x dataframe contains more values than the ones you posted. In your example, the number of rows equals the number of columns, that's why the commenters couldn't find a problem with it. The problem is not evident in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the 'row/column' index by using `match`, `cbind` it and assign the 'timeStamp' elements to the positions specified by the index in 'mat'.

```
 mat[cbind(match(x$meme, rownames(mat)),
             match(x$webId, colnames(mat)))] <- x$timeStamp

 mat
 #     428 2679 68814 948
 #2505  13   11     8   3
 #2510  16    6    14   1
 #2501   7    4     5  10
 #2508  12    2     9  15
```

Checking with the results from the `for` loop

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(x))
    mat1[rownames(mat1)==x[i,"meme"],
             colnames(mat1)==x[i,"webId"]]<-x[i,"timeStamp"]

 mat1
 #     428 2679 68814 948
 #2505  13   11     8   3
 #2510  16    6    14   1
 #2501   7    4     5  10
 #2508  12    2     9  15
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(21)
x1 <- data.frame(meme= rep(sample(1000), each=200), 
   webId= rep(sample(35000, 200, replace=FALSE), 1000), 
      timeStamp=rnorm(1000*200))
set.seed(324)
mat2 <- matrix(, 1000, 200, 
    dimnames=list(sample(unique(x1$meme)),sample(unique(x1$webId))))
mat3 <- mat2

system.time({
  mat2[cbind(match(x1$meme, rownames(mat2)),
         match(x1$webId, colnames(mat2)))] <- x1$timeStamp
     })
 # user  system elapsed 
 #  0.181   0.001   0.181 

system.time({

 for(i in 1:nrow(x1))
    mat3[rownames(mat3)==x1[i,"meme"],
            colnames(mat3)==x1[i,"webId"]]<-x1[i,"timeStamp"]

 })
# user  system elapsed 
#172.588  10.445 183.062 

 identical(mat2, mat3)
 #[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x <- data.frame(meme=rep(c(2501, 2505, 2508, 2510), each=4),
    webId= rep(c(68814, 2679, 948, 428), 4), timeStamp= sample(16))
set.seed(33)
mat <- matrix(, 4, 4, dimnames=list(sample(unique(x$meme)),
    sample(unique(x$webId))))
mat1 <- mat
```

Comment: @ZahraAminolroaya  Added some benchmarks.  The `for` loop in the current state is very slow compared to the `match`.  It may be possible to improve the timings in `for` loop.  But, I think the vectorized approach would be better here.